# Getting mixed results with key word searches

Tags: search

I am having a hard time understanding why some keywords in fields that are marked as "Use this field’s values as search keywords" are not showing in the results but others are. For example, I have a field in one entry that contains words like "batman, superman, spiderman". When I search for some of those terms, it shows the entry is shown. Now on a separate entry, the same field but with these keywords "mickey, donald, goofy". When I search those terms, no results are displayed.

How is it possible that one entry's keywords yield results, but the other entry's keywords do not?

Comment: Can you run `craft resave/entries --update-search-index=1` from your project's root and see if that helps?

Comment: I tried and received this message: Command 'craft' not found.

Comment: Recent versions of Craft are lacking bat file that allowed usage of `craft` command on windows. Use this command with php prefix - `php craft resave/entries --update-search-index=1`